# Crazy datetime values stored as weird floats in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, types, puzzle

OK, I'm not expecting anyone to be able to figure this out, but perhaps I am too pessimistic?

I'm reading the SQLite database generated by the awesome music player [AIMPv3](http://www.aimp.ru/), but it uses something *wonky* for storing the dates songs were played, added, etc.

So here's the table. I can provide a lot more if it's desired. Can you crack this code?!

```
          English             |      Stored As
------------------------------+-----------------
Date      2011.02.24 14:21:54 | 40598.5985614005
------------------------------+------------------
Date      2011.02.24 14:22:38 | 40598.5990576852
------------------------------+------------------
Date      2011.04.28 08:56:30 | 40661.3725871875
------------------------------+------------------
Date      2011.04.28 09:02:06 | 40661.3764806134
------------------------------+------------------
Date      2012.11.09 15:55:12 | 41222.663348912
------------------------------+------------------
```

Any help with this problem would be *very* much appreciated! I also have a highly varieted collection of this data, so don't hesitate to ask for additional test data.

---

**EDIT:** Here's the PHP function I'm using to convert Excel datetimes to Epochs:

```
function convertFromExcelDateTimeToEpoch($excelDateTime)
{
    $d = floor($excelDateTime);
    $t = $excelDateTime - $d;
    return (abs($d) > 0) ? ( $d - 25569 ) * 86400 + $t * 86400 : $t * 86400;
}
```

Comment: When I query the database for the datetime, I get back "41222.663348912". I wish to display to the user the English date equivalent "2012-11-09 15:55:12". But I have *no* idea what to do to get to that conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duration is milliseconds.

Date is (fractional) number of days since January 1st, 1900.

Comment: Actually it is days since 1900-01-01.  This is how Microsoft Excel and some other products manage date/times.

Comment: Woah! How did you figure that one out?!

Comment: Just run this in PostgreSQL: `SELECT '2011.02.24 14:21:54'::timestamp - interval '40598.59 days'` and it gave me  almost exactly `Jan 1st 1900`

Comment: That was so it!!! I'm happy you both knew this trivia and so quickly imparted it to me!

Comment: I actually didn't know this. But I love puzzles like this one :-)

Comment: AIMP is written in Delphi, and this happens to be Delphi's native `TDateTime` format (which originates from Windows' OLE date format).